# How to animate 3d Reconstructed face models

Tags: animation, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

I'm making an app that is based on unity3d game engine and targeted to IOS and Android platform. The core function of this app is that : users needs to input a 2d frontal face photo and the app will produce a 3d reconstructed face model which looks like the 2d face in the photo. I did some research and found the algorithm on github:

https://github.com/patrikhuber/eos.

I implemented the algorithm in unity3d and it looked good. But the face they provide can't do animation(because it's an triangle mesh). What I need for this app is an animated face which can do all kinds of human expressions. The best software for this kind of purpose I found is faceGen, but their technology is not suitable for mobile device. So I want to ask if there are any articles, reference or forums that discuss this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to render 3D data in real time is to use PCL(Point Cloud Library)
http://www.pointclouds.org/news/2012/05/29/pcl-goes-mobile-with-ves-and-kiwi/
Hope it can help